# Running MBean inside tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jmx, mbeans

I have registered few MBeans in my web application (running under tomcat7) and i am able to see them on jconsole.The exposed methods are getting invoked properly.

I have got certain utilities in my app which needs database connections, they can ask for connection from dbcp. These utilities work fine if called from servlet or a quartz job. But when i try to call those utilities from MBean's exposed method it fails to get connection from dbcp. It seems that mbeans are running as a standalone program and are not running under servlet context.

My question is, it their something that i am missing here ? It that possible ? How ?

---

- On jconsole mbeans are listed under tomcat process.
- I am getting mbean server like this 
  `MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();`

How i register mbean -

```
AdminService adminService = new AdminService();
ObjectName admin = new ObjectName("AdminS:type=AdminServiceMBean");
mbs.registerMBean(adminService, admin);
```

How i get connection from dbcp (ConnectionManager)

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context ctx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/adminService");
c = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: More details for 'it fails to get connection from dbcp' ? Also how did you regsiter MBeans and how are you getting connection from DBCP?

Comment: @rkosegi  It gives Naming Exception as i am asking connection using Jndi